# Error trying to publish Flattened contracts on Etherscan - DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique

Tags: solidity, remix, etherscan, chainlink

I flattened my files and they compile no problem on Remix, but when I try to upload them to Etherscan, they won't accept it with the error:

```
 Compiler debug log:
Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI (General Exception, unable to get compiled [bytecode])
For troubleshooting, you can try compiling your source code with the Remix - Solidity IDE and check for exceptions

Compiler Warning(s):

DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique.
    --> APIConsumer.sol:1095:5:
     |
1095 |     ENSResolver_Chainlink resolver = ENSResolver_Chainlink(s_ens.resolver(linkSubnode))
     |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This is the first part of my APIConsumer file before I flattened it.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";

contract APIConsumer is ChainlinkClient {
    using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;
  
    bytes32 public api_data;
    address private oracle;
    bytes32 private jobId;
    uint256 private fee;
```

After I flattened it (to which I uploaded to etherscan):

```
// File: @chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vendor/ENSResolver.sol


pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

abstract contract ENSResolver {
  function addr(bytes32 node) public view virtual returns (address);
}
```

And the file carries on with all the functions it inherits for another 1000 lines.

Did I do something wrong with flattening? I don't want to disturb peace and up breaking things just to publish my programs as my contracts work fine. How would I debug this problem?

EDIT: The other sighting of ENSResolver in the file:

```
  /**
   * @notice Sets the stored oracle and LINK token contracts with the addresses resolved by ENS
   * @dev Accounts for subnodes having different resolvers
   * @param ensAddress The address of the ENS contract
   * @param node The ENS node hash
   */
  function useChainlinkWithENS(address ensAddress, bytes32 node) internal {
    s_ens = ENSInterface(ensAddress);
    s_ensNode = node;
    bytes32 linkSubnode = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(s_ensNode, ENS_TOKEN_SUBNAME));
    ENSResolver_Chainlink resolver = ENSResolver_Chainlink(s_ens.resolver(linkSubnode));
    setChainlinkToken(resolver.addr(linkSubnode));
    updateChainlinkOracleWithENS();
  }

  /**
   * @notice Sets the stored oracle contract with the address resolved by ENS
   * @dev This may be called on its own as long as `useChainlinkWithENS` has been called previously
   */
  function updateChainlinkOracleWithENS() internal {
    bytes32 oracleSubnode = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(s_ensNode, ENS_ORACLE_SUBNAME));
    ENSResolver_Chainlink resolver = ENSResolver_Chainlink(s_ens.resolver(oracleSubnode));
    setChainlinkOracle(resolver.addr(oracleSubnode));
  }
```

Comment: Please inclde the part of the code where ENSResolver_Chainlink resolver = ENSResolver_Chainlink(s_ens.resolver(linkSubnode)) appears, that seems to be the actual problem

Comment: I do not know what your purpose is to use a flattened contract, but for the sake of efficiency, I use hardhat to verify my contracts through the Standard-Json-Input method. Read the docs. You only need to know like 4 commands to get started with it.

Comment: I typically use brownie to verify my contracts but it one day stopped publishing my contracts. I'll give that a shot. And thank you @JulissaDC, I ended up deleting the _Chainlink to the ENSResolver and got rid of that error... only to find several more (just warnings of unused variables and mismatches of bytecode). I'll give Gray's advice a shot. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Remix Flattener trimmed a piece of the name of that abstract contract. This approach worked for me:

1. Flatten contract using Remix IDE plugin
2. Paste it inside the Etherscan verification field
3. Rename `abstract contract ENSResolver` to `abstract contract ENSResolver_Chainlink`
4. Hit "Verify"